# Automatically offer to set execute permission on shell scripts

Tags: permissions, zsh, executable

I use shell scripts a lot. Practically every time, I create the script and try to run it, and get the permission error because I forgot to set `+x`. This seems like a huge hassle, is there a way to make my shell (`zsh`) automatically ask whether I would like to add the execute perm and try again, instead of just giving me the error?

I know I can just `source my.sh`, but sourcing is not the same as running with `./my.sh` and I would like the latter.

Comment: I hope not! Automatically making scripts executable sounds like a huge security risk. Seriously, spend some more time at it and it'll become habit to `chmod +x`.

Comment: @KGIII Not automatically executing, but a prompt saying "Do you want to add +x permission? (y/N)".

Comment: You could probably kinda accomplish this with alias. You could alias something like 'run' into `chmod +x` and then `run script.sh` and each time it'd set the permissions to executable. It wouldn't add much overhead, and you'd just have to learn to 'run' your scripts. Would that work? There's no automatic switching system that I've ever heard of. That's the best I can think of.

Comment: You could just do `zsh my.sh`, then you wouldn't need to worry about the permissions of the script. (or `bash my.sh` or `sh my.sh`, depending on the type of script you have).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating scripts, consider creating [functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html) (and converting existing scripts into functions). That way, you'll never have to worry about permissions again.

Scripts are easily converted to functions:

1. Remove the `.sh` extension from the file name. (Technically optional, but [that's the convention](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/tree/master/Functions).)
2. Make sure the file's parent dir is in your `$fpath`.
3. [`autoload`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Autoloading-Functions) your function in your `.zshrc`.

If you need different functions for different projects, consider using https://github.com/direnv/direnv. That way, each project can have its own `$fpath` and `autoload`ed functions.

Answer (score 0):

This Might help:

```
function command_permission() {
  # Get the command being run
  local cmd="${1}"
  local cmd=$(echo "${cmd}" | awk '{print $1}' )

  # Check if it starts with "./" and if the file doesn't have execute permission
  if [[ "${cmd}" =~ ^\./ && ! -x "${cmd#./}" ]]; then
    # Prompt for permission to chmod +x the file
    read -rq "REPLY?${cmd#./} is not executable. Do you want to make it executable (y/n)? "
    "$cmd" "$@"

    if [[ "${REPLY}" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
      # Make the file executable
      chmod +x "${cmd#./}"
    fi

    # Add a newline after the prompt
    echo ""
  fi
}

# Set the preexec function to be called before running each command
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook preexec command_permission
```